# Match given strings in a string and output an array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

Let's say I have a string like

> "Student - John Doe ate apples"
>
> "Student - Bob ate oranges"

I know this sentence consists of: `":type - :who ate :noun`

Is there a way to get an array of actions, utilising both strings such as :

```
$arr = [
   "type" => "Student",
   "who" => "John Doe",
   "noun" => "apples"
];

$arr2 = [
   "type" => "Student"
   "who" => "Bob",
   "noun" => "oranges"
];
```

What is the way to achieve this in php?

<sub>- I couldn't think of any way to achieve it so I can't put any code chunks.</sub>

<sub>- Probably I couldn't even name the question correctly, I'd appreciate a better name if you have any idea</sub>

Comment: If you know the actions and the noun will always be single words, you can do it. Otherwise there's not really a way to tell which word goes with which part unless your application understands how English works, which is much more complicated than just pulling text out of a string.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I simplified the strings. I know noun is one word, "ate" is static. Only "who" can be 1 or 2 words. The rest are I know for sure they are 1 word. Now is it possible?

Comment: Why an -1 and mark as close? It's totally logical question and achievable programatically. At least give a reason why.

Comment: It wasn't me, if you're addressing me. I think with the more consistent format after your edit it's definitely possible.

Comment: No it wasn't for you surely.

Comment: You can try turning your pattern into a regular expression. But regular expressions are pretty limited, so this is not a good way to achieve real natural language processing, which requires sophisticated parsing.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I absolutely know. But, unlike given answer, I wanted to know a regular expression type of solution. I'd highly appreciate if you can give an example. I'm not trying to achieve complex language strings - they are just robotic sentences and I know possible values of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also split the string on the patterns of characters that divide the different parts.

```
$result = array_combine(['type', 'who', 'noun'], preg_split('/ - | ate /', $example));
```

This should work reliably, assuming there's not a Bob ate who ate an ate or something like that.

Comment: Thanks! The one you had selected before is definitely more robust, though. If you use something simple like this you do have to be careful that any string you're splitting on isn't included in any of the pieces you're trying to separate.

Comment: You're right. For simpler cases, I'd use this, for complex ones I'd use the other one. Thanks again for this trick! _Someone downvoted you so I can't bring your vote to +1 :(_

Comment: No worries. I don't care about the points. Everyone's entitled to their opinion. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression with named groups. This assumes the input string is `$str`:

```
preg_match("/^(?<type>\w+)\s+-\s+(?<who>\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\s+ate\s+(?<noun>\w+)$/", 
           $str, $match);
```

This will set `$match` to a bit more than needed, but you can just grab from it what you need:

```
[
   0 => "Student - John Doe ate apples",
   "type" => "Student",
   1 => "Student",
   "who" => "John Doe",
   2 => "John Doe",
   "noun" => "apples",
   3 => "apples"
]
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That is a pretty clever solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can actually be done without any regex if you really do have the strict rules given in your updated question.  First split by the dash to get the type, then split the rest by "ate" to get the person and the noun.

```
$strings = array("Student - John Doe ate apples", "Student - Bob ate oranges");
$breakdown = array();

foreach($strings as $line)
{
    $mainParts = explode("-", $line);
    $type = trim($mainParts[0]);
    $subPart = explode(" ate ", $mainParts[1]);
    $who = trim($subPart[0]);
    $noun = trim($subPart[1]);

    $breakdown[] = array("type" => $type, "who" => $who, "noun" => $noun);
}

var_dump($breakdown);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c9d6855f2f5993deadc039d71dcfcff27b67ccb4)

Comment: I have many types and this is only one type. I'd appreciate if you can add the regex type of solution too.

Comment: @senty By "type", do you mean the "Student" part?  If so, this will work for any "type", as long as it precedes the dash, as you indicated it would.  Also, regex has significant overhead and is often overkill for simple situations.

Comment: yes. Thanks for giving me an approach though. I'd tinker around to see which of the given answers fit my situation most